# Chef: Ruby gem dependency

Tags: chef-infra

I've install this `java-properties` gem into my workstation ruby instance.

So now, I'mable to serialize a config object to a properties file:

```
hash = {:foo => "bar"}
JavaProperties.write(hash, "path/to/my.properties")
```

So, this `gem` is not installed on a new chef node, but it required in order to perform this ruby code.

How should I deal with it? So, should I install `java-properties gem` into the new chef node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `chef_gem` resource to install a gem only for the instance of Ruby that is dedicated to the chef-client.

For more details, see:
https://docs.chef.io/resource_chef_gem.html

Comment: This is correct for older Chef but we have a better way now, see below.

Answer (score 3):

While you can use `chef_gem` for this, the simpler option is to add `gem 'java-properties'` to your cookbook's `metadata.rb`. That will handle downloading and installing the gem for you. You will need to add the `require` to where ever you are using it though.